# Ordinal logistic regression prediction and accuracy using statsmodels

Tags: logistic-regression, prediction, accuracy, statsmodels

I am trying to do a ordinal logistic regression analysis using statsmodels. However, the predictions I'm getting are vastly different from that I get when using SciKit-Learn `LogisticRegression`.

I'm using a dataset similar to the following. The aim is to predict the `quality` (on a scale of `1-10`) based on the composition of `chlorides` and `sulphates`.

| chlorides | sulphates | quality |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0.076 | 0.56 | 5 |
| 0.098 | 0.68 | 5 |
| 0.092 | 0.65 | 5 |
| 0.075 | 0.58 | 6 |
| 0.076 | 0.56 | 5 |
| ... | ... | ... |

The code I'm using:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn import metrics
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from statsmodels.miscmodels.ordinal_model import OrderedModel

y = df['quality']
X = df[['chlorides', 'sulphates']]
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.4, random_state=20)

mod_probe = OrderedModel(y_train, X_train, distr='logit')
res_log = mod_probe.fit(method='bgfs')

predicted = res_log.model.predict(res_log.params, np.array(X_test)[:, None])
```

`predicted` sample:

```
array([[[0.00394536, 0.02194635, 0.32950146, 0.47302334, 0.15847723,
         0.01310626]],

       [[0.01405662, 0.07326043, 0.57761266, 0.2806573 , 0.05073693,
         0.00367607]],

       [[0.02683372, 0.12930636, 0.63716285, 0.17780338, 0.02698959,
         0.0019041 ]],

       ...,
```

When I do

```
metrics.accuracy_score(y_test, predicted)
```

I get the error

```
ValueError: Classification metrics can't handle a mix of multiclass and unknown targets
```

I have done many hours of searching on this but can't seem to crack it. Any help would be highly appreciated. Many thanks.